# Command aapt is not found

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-tools, aapt

I wanted to use the aapt command on a Mac with the android sdk (folder /build-tools/24.0.1). But whenever I try to use the command I get the message that the command is not found (aapt/aapt2). This doesn't work neither in the Terminal nor in Android Studio.

If I list the available commands in the 24.0.1. folder in the Terminal, there is a star sign next to both commands, which is described as:

```
A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.
```

How can I enable these commands again? Updating the build-tools didn't help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Check your path and check if it is correct.

Just edit your `~/.bash_profile` add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/PATH/TO/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/x.x.x
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and write if it worked or not as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you! I would just like to highlight that in my case, I had to invalidate cache/restart before running the aapt command once again.

Answer (score 13):

Base on @josedlujan answer, here is a quick steps to make `aapt` command work on Mac

```
# First, run this to see all available build-tools version
ls ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools

# Then open file
nano ~/.zshrc 

# Add this line to the file and save
export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/<version>

## Run
source ~/.zshrc
```